# How to display custom font on Adobe XD mobile cloud document?

Tags: fonts, text, adobe-xd

I have a prototype which uses a few third party fonts and 1 custom icon font.
When previewing the prototype on my PC, everything is displayed correctly, but when I try to test it with my Android smartphone, there are fonts missing.

Is there any way to deal with this issue?
I understand that I can convert all texts into paths, but I can't do it all at once, I have to convert them manually.

Also, I could not make the live preview to work on my smartphone, connected via a USB cable to my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: To convert everything in one go, select all (Ctrl+A). Then right click and choose *Path  > Convert to Path*

Comment: Ctrl+A selects everything but on right-clicking, it will convert only the element which I right-clicking on top.

Comment: No. that isn't right. I just tested this. All text items are changed to outlines following this procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Other answer is not true, you can do this easily by adding the font to your mobile device. I only did this on iPhone but I bet it works on android as well.

1. Download the fonts from safari/web browser to your device.
2. Download iOS app iFont
3. Click import font
4. Follow on screen instructions (click install, open iOS settings, click install font).

Reopen XD and you will no longer have the “7 fonts missing” errors and your fonts will load automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, only fonts listed in the Adobe Fonts tab are compatible with the Adobe XD mobile app. And the Live Preview function, you can't preview from windows to android.
Check [this link](https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/adobe-xd-mobile-faq.html) to learn more